# Where to meet travel partner at JFK (Terminal 4 arrivals)

Tags: usa, airports, new-york-city, jfk

I'm flying in to JFK on a Delta International flight, which I believe lands at Terminal 4.  My partner is also flying in on a COPA International flight (and lands at around the same time). I believe COPA also use T4

This being the case. What is our best chance for meeting at the airport? I presume we must both (separately?) go through immigration control, then (possibly together?) can go through baggage claim / customs? Or is there a chance to meet prior to immigration control?

If one flight is delayed, meeting somewhere within the Terminal is probably a good idea. Any recommendations?  I'm struggling to find a decent map of T4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have no chance to meet prior to immigration in Terminal 4.  International flights are funneled via hallways directly to the border control so the best you can hope for is meet in one of the hallways leading to that area or meet immediately following the customs [right before you exit](http://www.jfkiat.com/maps/arrivals.pdf).  Unfortunately there is no floor plan of the gates and hallways that is publicly available to display.

I would opt for the former option since there is I believe only a single hallway leading into the passport control area.

Comment: IIRC, there's no-where really to wait between the gate and immigration area in T4, though it has been a few years since I flew Delta into JFK. Wouldn't suggesting to the OP to meet in a cafe outside customs be better?

Comment: @Gagravarr Not really since there is no real cafe's on the first floor at the exit.   There are a couple of coffee stands and some sitting spaces but they are usually taken given how busy T4 is.  Continuing with my personal view of JFK sux.

Comment: Thanks kindly. The map of T4 arrivals is certainly a help!